# Plot lines from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want to plot for each column a line, from the origin to the point (a,b)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2], [7,3]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df.head(10)
df.plot(kind='line')
```

[image: Here the plot that I get]

But I want 2 lines, one from (0,0) to (1,2) and the second from (0,0) to (7,3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

for i in range(0, 2):
    pl.plot([0, df.iloc[i][0]], [0,df.iloc[i][1]], label=(i+1))
pl.legend(loc='upper left')
pl.show()
```

It's not elegant but it works.

[image]

Comment: @dooms. Is it OK now?